# How could show x and y labels on PyQt canvas?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

I try to make desktop application with Python and PyQt. 
what I want to make is simple, load impedance data from txt file, and plotting it.

I made `canvas` on my dialog and plot lines on it, but the `xlabel` and `ylabel` is not represented.

Label problem on GUI

[image]

When I run the script without GUI, it show the label very well.

No GUI

[image]

It seems that the size of axes is too big to show labels on layout. Could I control it?

```py
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import uic

uiFile = "../UI/DataAnalyzer.ui"

class MainDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self, None)
        uic.loadUi(uiFile, self)

        self.fileDialog_btn_1.clicked.connect(self.loadFile)

        self.fig = plt.Figure()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.canvas.draw()    

    def loadFile(self):
        fileNames = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self)
        self.Z_processing(fileNames)

    def Z_processing(self, fileNames):
        # print(fileNames[0])
        # print(type(fileNames[0]))

        self.ax.cla()

        for file in fileNames[0]:
            data = np.loadtxt(file)
            self.ax.plot(data[:, 0], data[:, 1])
            self.ax.plot(data[:, 0], data[:, 2])

        self.ax.grid()
        self.ax.set_xlim([0, 20e6])
        self.canvas.draw()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mainDialog = MainDialog()
mainDialog.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling [`self.fig.tight_layout()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/tight_layout_api.html?highlight=tight#module-matplotlib.tight_layout) before drawing the canvas in `Z_processing()`

Comment: thanks to your reply. i have already do that, but it is not working.
when i use add_axes() with geometry input, or when i increase the size of layout, it show better layout.